# How can I take better pictures of an Apple Watch screen using an iPhone?

Tags: technique, iphone, tips

I lost my phone and all of the photos on it.  I have an Apple Watch, and it has my favorite photos on it.  To pair it to my new phone, I have to erase all of the data.  There’s no way to “save” these photos other than taking a picture of them displayed on the watch face.  They’re mostly pictures of people and my cats.  I have the iPhone 13 pro max.  I really don’t know anything about photography, so any tips would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: While I'm no Apple expert, I think you may have an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. I would suggest asking on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) if there is a way to get your photos directly from the watch without trying to take photos of them.

Comment: Have you check if you have sync of your photos with iCloud?

Comment: Was the phone properly synced - to a computer or iCloud? If so, they're all on there. If not, then yes, you're back to trying to take photos of a tiny screen with a curved edge.

Comment: No, it wasn’t synced and there’s no way to export them.

Comment: now in WatchOS 8, you can share photos right from your Apple Watch according to this article [link](https://www.imore.com/how-share-photos-your-apple-watch)

Comment: Normally, I'd agree that this is an Apple ecosystem problem (i.e., an X-Y problem), but [this Apple Discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251299168) suggests the only way to get the photos off is to take photos of them.

Comment: Doesn't that point back to it being an Apple ecosystem problem, @scottbb? Of course, if they give you the tools and you don't use 'em...

Comment: @FreeMan not really. Sounds like OP is following the only advice that is possible to them (take photos of the images on the watch). So the question is, how to take better photos of images on the watch face? It's a crappy way to preserve/recover images, but the question is definitely in the realm of photography.